# Responsive Images won't Scale with Firefox as screen size is adjusted. Works in other Browsers

Tags: css, firefox, responsive-design

I'm new to responsive images but have figured out how to get my images to scale in Safari, Opera, and Chrome (don't know about IE) with the following CSS:

```
img {   
  max-width: 100%;   
  width: auto;   
  height: auto; 
}
```

As the screen size is changed, the image scales. In Firefox, the image doesn't scale, unless I change width:auto to width:100%;  Then Safari scrunches up the image to nothing upon load or reload; although, clearing cash makes it full size. I'm working on Drupal with the Zen 7.5-dev responsive theme. And I'm keeping my css files in SASS, but this is probably just a CSS issue. Maybe I've missed something on the HTML 5 or CSS3 side of things.

Anyway, I got things to work by overriding the image width a Firefox specific directive like this:

```
/* Make Firefox images scale with screen width. The width:100% messes up on Safari */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {  
  img {   
    width: 100%;   
  }
}
```

I don't think I should have to do this, and googling doesn't seem to come across this issue.

Comment: Can you provide an example, with some markup and actual images?

Answer (score 9):

This is the default CSS that is used for responsive Images:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width:100%;
}
```

And this is the indispensable Javascript: [Bongard.net](https://web.archive.org/web/20080206142139/http://www.bongard.net/blog/2007/12/07/browsererkennung-mit-javascript-browserweiche/)

*Thanks to David Bongard for the Javascript.*

Now add the following to the "if safari" rule of the Script:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("img").length; i++) {
  document.getElementsByTagName("img")[i].style.width = "auto";
  }
```

Safari wants `width:auto;` the rest of the browsers i tested are happy with `width:100%;`

Answer (score 7):

This works for me

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {  
    img{
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {    
     img{
        max-width: 100%;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Add some more details.

Comment: i had same problem but fixed with your codes , thank you

Answer (score 5):

I have similar problem, and found out setting `max-width` on the wrapper element kinda solves the issue. (Only tested with Firefox 23, but it should works with earlier Firefox too.) See also these JSFiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/CLUGX/ (demonstrate the issue on Firefox)
- http://jsfiddle.net/CLUGX/1/ (uses `max-width` on wrapper to fix the issue)
- http://jsfiddle.net/CLUGX/4/ (demonstrate that responsive sizing works, try resizing inner frame)

Before max-width:

[image: before max-width]

After max-width:

[image: after max-width]

One thing to note, however, if you happens to set `padding` on wrapper element, it won't be taken into `img`'s width calculation and will cause inconsistent results between Firefox and Safari (http://jsfiddle.net/CLUGX/3/):

[image: gahhh]

Answer (score 2):

Chances are your image is inside a shrink-wrapping container, which then has to compute it's width based on the width of the image.  And then the max-width of the image is 100% of the container's width.

If that's what's going on, the CSS spec doesn't actually define the behavior of such markup, where the parent's width depends on the child and the child's width depends on the parent.

See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=823483 for some discussion on the issue.

Comment: Thank you Boris, that gives me a direction to look. Drupal has a tendency to put out multiple divs, and multiple classes on each div.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the width for image in px or gave padding or used display:table instead of display:block for the image, then image responsiveness will not work properly on  some/all browsers

Answer (score 1):

Well after trying all sorts of codes and fidles, this simple edition on my css did the trick for me:

```
img {width: 100%;}
```

Simply then where you wish your images to resize, define them without adding the "width" parameter (sizing to original from source); and then if you do wish to fix their size, simply add the "width" parameter on SRC style (regular width="" definition won't work). If it's an inline image on your paragraph, simply wrap it in a div and align that div to whatever side you'd like. Reeeeally simple!

It works both for Google, Firefox and IE. Cheers!

Comment: One additional tip, encapsulate the new img css style with a responsive rule so that it is only applied when you are actually having to be responsive: @media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {img {width: 100%;}}

Answer (score 0):

I have just had this problem and found a solution: When I set the img max-width in my CSS sheet, nothing happens - the image won't scale. When I set max-width in the page itself - where the image is called, it works in all browsers and on all devices.

No:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;   }
```

Yes:

```
<img src ="image.jpg" style="max-width:100%; height:auto;">
```

If anyone can shed some light of wisdom on this, please do.

Comment: This is not an answer - this is a question.

Answer (score 0):

I used Kridsada Thanabulpong's jsfiddle but only got it to work when I removed display:table from the div wrapping my image.